# How can I filter a single category in UICollectionView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, filtering

I'm new in swift and I have some problem while I try to filter some categories in my UICollectionView.

Here  my code to get all articles for all the categories.

```
    func getArticlesforCategory(category: String) -> Int {
    var result : Int = 0
    for article in self.allArticles {
        if category == article.category {
            result += 1
        }
    }
    return result
    }
```

How can I filter only one single category, for example "test"?

I get all the categories by parsing xml from wordpress website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` function to filter your array :

```
func getArticlesforCategory(category: String) -> Int {
    let filteredArray = allArticles.filter( {$0.category == category }) // Here you have filtered array
    return filteredArray.count // If you want number of items pass count of filtered array
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sharad, but I have some problem with the code it' retrieve me "ViewController has no member filteredarray" Could you provide private help?

Comment: I am defining filteredArray in that function only. Did you remove let from that ? And if you can share code send me at sharadchauhan0504@gmail.com

Comment: Sharad I replied to you via gmail.

Answer (score 1):

try below line:

```
let result = self.allArticles.filter { $0.category == "test" }.count
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/2893557-filter), try this code

```
func getFilteredArray(category: String) -> [ array of your objects] {
    let filteredArray = allArticles.filter( {$0.category == category })
    return filteredArray
}
```